# Sign XML using RSA from C# to php

Tags: c#, php, .net, rsa

I'm trying to digitally sign XML using RSA using PHP and I already have the code in C# but when trying to sign the XML in PHP and verify it in c# it fails.

Sign Code in C#:

```
 RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaCryptoServiceProvider = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
            rsaCryptoServiceProvider.FromXmlString(GetCertificates(certificateSerialNumber).PrivateKey.ToXmlString(true));

            RSACryptoServiceProvider.UseMachineKeyStore = true;

            rsaCryptoServiceProvider.ExportParameters(false);
            rsaCryptoServiceProvider.KeySize = 2048;
return Convert.ToBase64String(rsaCryptoServiceProvider.SignData(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(elementsValue), CryptoConfig.MapNameToOID("SHA256")));
```

Verify Code in C#:

```
RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaCryptoServiceProvider = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)GetCertificates(certificateSerialNumber).PublicKey.Key;

            RSACryptoServiceProvider.UseMachineKeyStore = true;

            rsaCryptoServiceProvider.ExportParameters(false);
            rsaCryptoServiceProvider.KeySize = 2048;

            byte[] Signature;

            try
            {
                Signature = Convert.FromBase64String(signature);
            }
            catch
            {
                return false;
            }

            return rsaCryptoServiceProvider.VerifyData(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(elementsValue), CryptoConfig.MapNameToOID("SHA256"), Signature);
```

Sign Code in PHP:

```
$rsa = new Crypt_RSA();
        $rsa->loadKey($privateKey);

        $rsa->setSignatureMode(CRYPT_RSA_SIGNATURE_PKCS1);

        $rsa->setHash('sha256');
        $hashed = $rsa->hash->hash($encryptedData);
base64_encode($rsa->sign($hashed));
```

When I use the above PHP code to sign the XML string and try to verify the value in C# is return false, can anyone help with this.

Thank you.

Comment: `Encoding.Unicode` in the C# code specifies UTF-16LE, did you consider this in the PHP code? Also, `sign()` in the PHP code hashes implicitly (analogous to `SignData()` in the C# code), i.e. the PHP code seems to hash twice because of `$hashed = ...`.

Comment: @Topaco, actually for the encoding no I didn't consider it in Php and I really don't know what is the equivalent for `Encoding.Unicode` in Php. and for the hash I remove the duplicates and the sign value from c# is not the same for the Php. Thanks

Comment: Try [`mb_convert_encoding()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php). Regarding the hashing: In the PHP code, as in the C# code, the unhashed data has to be passed (since `SignData()` and `sign()` *implicitly* hash).

Comment: @Topaco, you saved my life. Thanks for your help. works correctly as the issue was only in the encoding, and removing the duplicate hashing in PHP code. thans again